# Cannot assign reason to dependency

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I try to add a `reason` to a dependency like:

```
implementation("foo:bar:0.1.0") { reason = "test" }
```

But get an error, stating that "val cannot be reassigned". 
I can't find the source I got this from, but from my memory this was the way. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html suggests it should be `{ because "test" }`

Comment: Oh my .. you are totally correct! If you dont' mind to add an answer, I will happily accept it.

Comment: Sure - an extra set of eyes always helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the example at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html#sec:documenting-dependencies it looks like it should be

```
implementation("foo:bar:0.1.0") { because("test") }
```